# Are maps from the Massachusetts State Transportation Library in the public domain?

Tags: united-states, copyright, intellectual-property, public-domain, massachusetts

[MBTA](https://www.mbta.com/) is the transit agency for Greater Boston, Massachussetts, USA.

The [website for the Massachusetts State Transportation Library](https://www.mass.gov/state-transportation-library) contains many old MBTA maps and other transit-related items. A user on Flickr has [collected a number of these maps](https://www.flickr.com/photos/vanshnookenraggen/albums/72157594460286528/), one of which is reproduced below.

[image: Old map of Boston]

I would like to use one of these old maps for a project (which may end up being commercial).

My questions:

1. What is the copyright status of these maps?
2. Are they in the public domain?
3. Can I use them commercially?
4. What if I modify them (mostly by removing/changing text for artistic purposes)?
5. Does the year of the map matter?

Thank you!

Comment: The "Permission" section of this map I found on Wikimedia Commons (https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1988_MBTA_subway_map.png) says that "This work is in the public domain in the United States because it was a Commonwealth of Massachusetts public record disseminated by a Commonwealth agency or the Massachusetts Archives." Seems like a good sign!